# Como fazer insert em uma posição diferente de zero numa lista vazia?

Tags: python, lista

Como eu posso inserir um valor em uma posição diferente de zero numa lista vazia?

Ex:

```
lista = []
.
.
.
lista.insert(3, 'valor')
```

Comment: Criar uma lista não vazia? Qual valor ficaria na posições de 0 a 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listas em Python tem o tamanho igual ao numero de elementos que contém - são diferentes de "arrays" ou "vetores" - muito embora, em alguns textos para iniciantes, elas sejam apresentadas como "vetores".

Então não há como inserir o 3º elemento em uma lista vazia - ele sempre vai ser o primeiro elemento - por que quais seriam então os elementos nas posições 0 e 1?

Dependendo do que você quiser fazer, pode ser que outra estrutura de dados possa ser melhor para você do que uma lista: você pode ter um dicionário e usa-lo com chaves numéricas, em vez de string por exemplo. E se usar sempre o método "get" as posições ainda não preenchidas do dicionário funcionam como se tivessem um valor padrão.

Isso é, em vez de uma `list` que vai ter 10 elementos, contendo "0" por padrão criada com:

```
dados = [0] * 10
```

Você pode criar um dicionário, e sempre acessa-lo com get:

```
dados = {}
...
valor = dados.get(2, 0)   # nesse caso, se dados[2] não estiver definido, o get retorna 0.
```

Se fizer isso, não é necessário criar todos os elementos do dicionário previamente. Já com uma lista, isso sempre será necessário.

Se a estrutura de dados que você precisa for para valores numéricos, nesse cado, o Python tem "array"s de verdade - vetores inicializados com um número para cada posição. Mas exceto para problemas muito especializados, o dicionário ou listas serão mais práticos - e se for um problem de natureza numérica, é melhor usar a biblitoeca numpy do que usar arrays nativos do Python em geral. (Os arrays do Python mesmo tendo posições "reais" para os elementos, ao contrário de listas, também precisam receber valores iniciais explícitos - o que dá no mesmo que as listas para a sua questão)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode escrever uma função capaz de preencher os 'espaços' vazios caso a lista não tenha o tamanho adequado usando um valor padrão, veja só:

```
def insert_at_pos( lst, pos, val, default=None ):

    if( len(lst) > pos ):
       lst.insert( pos, val )
    else:
        for _ in range( pos - len(lst) ):
            lst.append( default )
        lst.append( val )

    return lst
```

Testando:

```
l1 = []
l2 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l3 = [ 'foo', 'bar' ]

print( insert_at_pos( l1, 3, 'valor') )
print( insert_at_pos( l2, 3, 'valor') )
print( insert_at_pos( l3, 3, 'valor') )
```

Saída:

```
[None, None, None, 'valor']
[1, 2, 3, 'valor', 4, 5]
['foo', 'bar', None, 'valor']
```

Ou, especificando como preencher os espaços vazios:

```
l1 = []
l2 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l3 = [ 'foo', 'bar' ]

print( insert_at_pos( l1, 3, 'valor', 'VAZIO' ) )
print( insert_at_pos( l2, 3, 'valor', 'VAZIO' ) )
print( insert_at_pos( l3, 3, 'valor', 'VAZIO' ) )
```

Saída:

```
['VAZIO', 'VAZIO', 'VAZIO', 'valor']
[1, 2, 3, 'valor', 4, 5]
['foo', 'bar', 'VAZIO', 'valor']
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar uma versão customizada da List.

```
import collections
class MyList(collections.UserList):
    def insert(self, i, item):
        for _ in range(self.__len__(), i):
            self.append(None)
        super().insert(i, item)
```

Seu código ficaria

```
lista = MyList()
lista.insert(3, 'valor')
print(list)
```

Resultando em

> [None, None, None, 'valor']